# Running JSP application using tomcat 6.0 and Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat6

I am working on an academic project using Eclipse 3.X , jsp's, servlet's etc. The server i chosed to deploy my application is "Tomcat 6.0".

when i change any of my code in the application, i am facing problem with running the application. the changes in the code are not showing any affect even though i restart the server. the changes only get affected, if i **restart my eclipse**. i tried lot of ways by googling about integration of **eclipse with tomcat** but nothing worked?. I always have to restart the eclipse, to see my changes.

Please help me with this issue.

thanks in advance.

Comment: how are you deploying ? Using the tomcat adaptor that comes with eclipse ? or standalone in tomcat ?

Comment: Changes to what code? Does this code get compiled? If so, by what?

Answer (score 0):

You should simply be able to use the "republish" feature after saving/building.

Answer (score 0):

1, If the development path and deployment path is the same dictionary, make sure that the "Build Automatically" is checked, it's in "Project->Build Automatically", it can help you deploy the files which are changed.

2, If the development path and deployment path is not the same dictionary, you can write an ant task to deploy project.

Comment: In general, if things aren't updating as you expect, make sure Build Automatically is on.

Answer (score 0):

if u are running in eclipse it is running the tomcat server of eclipse so for changes to be affected it should be refresh so u have to restart eclipse better way is to use outside eclipse and use localhost and tomcat manager u can restart and can see the changes or use ajax

Comment: use ajax ? this will not at all help